# HBase components doesn't appear in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: hadoop, hbase, pentaho

I am trying to working with Pentaho, in order to build some big data solutions. But the Hadoop HBase components aren't appering in the dashboard. I don't understand why HBase doesn't appear, since HBase is up an running on my machine... I've been seeking for a solutions, but without success...

Answer (score 0):

Please check this property value 'hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period' set to 10 mins in hbase-default.xml to get rid of hbase exceptions.

Check that you have added zookeeper host in the hbase output host in pentaho data integration tool.

Have you read this [wiki](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Loading+Data+into+HBase) in order to load hbase data into pentaho.

Comment: My problem is even worse, since the HBase components are not even showing up in the dashboard (for instance, HBase Output, etc). I can't understand why. I am using PDI version 7.1 Spoon.

Comment: can you please post your error logs and moreover please check this thread stack http://forums.pentaho.com/archive/index.php/f-301-p-2.html.